# C# SQL Server database error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I got the following error for my code:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in
>   System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The UPDATE statement conflicted with the
>   FOREIGN KEY constraint
>
> "FK_TutorID". The conflict occurred in database "NPTC", table
>   "dbo.Tutor", column 'TutorID'.

This is my code:

```
// Instantiate a SqlConnection object with the COnnection String read.
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(strConn.ToString());

// Instantiate a sqlcommand object, provide a update sql statement to add
// class to tutor record specified by a classID
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("
    UPDATE TuitionClass 
    SET TutorID = @tutorID 
    FROM TuitionClass 
    INNER JOIN Tutor ON TuitionClass.tutorID = Tutor.tutorID 
                     AND TuitionClassID = @selectedTuitionClassID", conn);

// Define the parameter used in SQL statement, value for the parameter is retrieved 
// from class's property
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tutorID", TutorID);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@selectedTuitionClassID", tuitionClassID);

// open a Database connection
conn.Open();

// Execute the SQL statement
int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

// Close database connection
```

I'm not sure where it has gone wrong because I think my code is correct?

Comment: Code may be correct but the error message is telling you exactly what's wrong. You need to check out the foreign key relationship you have on that table.

Comment: `The conflict occurred in database "NPTC", table "dbo.Tutor", column 'TutorID'.`  this is your issue.  You're (probably) attempting to update the TutorID to a value that does not exist from the originating table

Comment: Why are you doing a JOIN in your UPDATE statement?   I don't see that it serves any purpose.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to set the TutorID on a TuitionClass row to a value that isn't found in the Tutor table.  Hence the foreign key constraint error.

Comment: This is why I think FK constraints are dumb.

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: @Hogan This is the reason why FK constraints exists. To not let people corrupt the data.

Comment: @robertfrickle sure, or the easier alternative... Not write code that corrupts the data. It is quite easy to do if you know what you are doing. This stuff exists because dbas are bored.

Answer (score 4):

You passed an invalid parameterer here:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tutorID", TutorID);
```

The `TutorID` does not match a `Tutor` in the database.